# Trying to replace character in string with a line break in helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, line-break

I'm trying to replace a ; in a string with a line break to then be displayed in my component. I'm currently using the code below to do this.

```
formatString: function(component, event, schemes) {
        var newSchemes = [];
        schemes.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry.RequiredFromClientMain__c != '') {
                var str = entry.RequiredFromClientMain__c;
                str = str.replace(/;/g,'<br>');
                entry.RequiredFromClientMain__c = str;
            }
            newSchemes.push(entry);
        });
        return newSchemes;
    },
```

Unfortunately, when I print the new string in my component I see the following:

[image]

How can I get an actual break line and not just the tag for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you may be approaching this from the wrong direction. Lightning, by default, encodes all unsafe characters so you don't accidentally get XSS injections. There's ways around this, but I'd say you can probably just use CSS instead.

```
formatString: function(component, event, schemes) {
  schemes.forEach(scheme =>
    scheme.RequiredFromClientMain__c = 
      (scheme.RequiredFromClientMain__c || '').replace(/;/g, '\n')
    );
  return schemes;
}
```

From there, use CSS to show the new lines:

```
<div class="show-newlines">{!v.output}</div>
```

And:

```
.show-newlines {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Additional work may be necessary if you're using SLDS, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for he response!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a security measure that prevents HTML injection.

You should use `aura:unescapedHtml` to render HTML but make sure that your source of data is safe:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml/specification

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I really appreciate it.